# Setting up local development environment for Umbraco

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, content-management-system, umbraco

I have inherited an Umbraco CMS project, the Umbraco instance and custom user controls exist on our test server as the initial build has been demo-ed to the client already.  I now need to take this on, the initial build was done by a freelance dev before my time here and no documentation exists on set up, deployment, etc.

The custom usercontrols were under source control and build ok, after a bit of bug fixing.  I have followed the following to try and get an instance of the Umbraco install and custom controls working on my machine for developing against.

http://slickjuanito.wordpress.com/2012/02/27/setting-up-umbraco-development-environment-in-visual-studio-2010/

http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/how-tos/getting-started-with-umbraco-what-is-next-after-you-install/setting-up-your-project-in-visual-studio

I am pointing the Umbraco web config at the database with the relevant content in and can access the back end of the CMS, however when i go to the Default.aspx i just get a blank page.  I have set VS2010 up to throw CLR exceptions and started the solution in debug mode to see if an error is being thrown and nothing.

Can anyone either suggest things to try and get it running properly or point me to some resources tha might help?

Thanks

Chris

Comment: Alrighy. Do you have IIS installed on your development environment or just WebMatrix? If IIS I can walk you through what I do, that works pretty well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have [IIS Express](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=1038) installed, what I have found easiest is to:

1. Copy the filesystem of the site from the server to a folder in the Inetpub of your local machine.
2. Create a site in IIS and point to those files.
3. In Visual Studio, click File, Open, Website, and then choose the site.

If you have the [MVC Framework](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=1491) installed, syntax highlighting will work for razor (.cshtml) scripts.

One step further would be to make a copy of the database and point the connection string to that copy. The copy could be restored to another database server, or if you have [SQL Server Express](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=23650) installed, you can run the copy locally as well.

Comment: Thanks, i had found the solution last night, however when i came to post the solution my SO profile doesn't have enough points for me to answer my own questions for 8 hours after posting.  That answer is spot on though with what i had to do.

Comment: Oh so sad... Well glad you got it worked out. Have fun coding.

Comment: This answer helped me so much in '12 and '13, but from Umbraco 6 on, things got a lot easier. I wrote about it in an aswer to a related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27882602/1091947