# Executing Umbraco 4.11.1 source code in visual studio 2010

Tags: umbraco, opencms

i have undoubtedly spent many hours to get Umbraco solved ..but no success.
What i want...is learning to work with Umbraco 4.11.1 version (i know Umbraco 5 is latest) but have very less knowledge about it. support from Umbraco also seems insufficient.

**I want to run Umbraco using visual studio 2010 Professional but no success..** first of all i couldnt find a source code for umbraco which i can understand. i downloaded source code from below link:

http://umbraco.codeplex.com/releases/view/98167

after downloading im getting following folder:
.nuget
Umbraco.Extensions
Umbraco.Site
UmbracoProject (Solution file)

but when im trying to open this solution file via visual studio 2010 im getting error :
saying 
Selected File is a solution file but created by a new version of the application.

I couldnot understand why i cant open the source code in visual studio ?
Please help me out. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How is this question related to OpenCms ? You should remove the tag in case it's not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your initial question seems to be answered by @DouglasLudlow; but in addition:

Umbraco 5 development was stopped months ago, Umbraco 4.11 is the latest version of Umbraco.

If you have a working Umbraco 4.x build then a good next step would be to watch the [free training videos](http://umbraco.com/products/umbracotv) that describe each part of Umbraco.  Specifically razor scripts are held in the Scripting Files section of the 'Developer' section of the Umbraco back-office - and in the macroScripts folder of your umbraco project.

[image]

Comment: hi amelvin.thanks for ur quick reply. i know it would be a little foolish. but i want to know the link u will download 4.11.1 umbraco. coz the link from where i have downloaded umbraco shows different folder structure.

Comment: This is a screenshot of the backoffice - not the code folder structure.  In Umbraco the code structure is not the same as represented by the backoffice - for example 'Scripting Files' are called 'macroScripts'; 'Macros' are stored in the database rather than the file structure and so on.

Comment: hi amelvin. so whats difference between Umbraco back-office and Umbraco Project . i thought both are the same. if not please explain.and thanks a ton for your valuable support.

Comment: For Umbraco some parts like master pages (templates in umbraco), razor scripts (Scripting Files in back office, macroScripts in project) and user controls are stored in the file system and accessible through the back office.  Some parts like document types and macro definitions are stored in the database and accessible through the back office.  So Umbraco stores some but not all of its parts in the project file structure, so they are not the same.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you are wanting to do actual development on the Umbraco core, you won't need to download the Umbraco source. To be able to open an Umbraco via Visual Studio to edit cshtml files, templates, etc., setup an Umbraco instance (either through WebMatrix or do it manually) and then open the project as a website.

Refer to [Setting up local development environment for Umbraco](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10296463/setting-up-local-development-environment-for-umbraco) for more detailed information.

Comment: Hi Douglas Ludlow, i followed ur way and could open a build umbraco 4.11.1 successfully. however i wonder i could not found any .cshtml pages in full source code.even i wonder how i start editing the project can u help me out the way they have stored their source code..

Comment: @Sangeeta, refer to amelvin's answer. Most of the work you are probably wanting to do can be done by logging into Umbraco backend. Umbraco will not include any cshtml files or templates when first installed. Consider installing a starter kit to get an idea of how it works.